# saving dataframe groupby rows to exactly two lines

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, python-3.8

I got a dataframe and I want to groupby the rows based on a specific column. Number of rows in each group will be at least 4 and at most 50. I want to save one column from the group into two lines. If the groupsize is even, let us say `2n`, then `n` rows in one line and the remaining `n` in the second line. If it is odd, `n+1` and `n` or `n` and `n+1` will do.

For example,

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data = """
id,name
1,A
1,B
1,C
1,D
2,E
2,F
2,ds
2,G
2, dsds
"""
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data))
```

I want to groupby `id`

`df.groupby('id',sort=False)`

and then get a dataframe like

```
    id  name
0   1   A B
1   1   C D
2   2   E F ds
3   2   G dsds
```

Comment: can you try `df.groupby([df.index // 2, df['id']]).agg(','.join)`

Comment: @Manakin I need exactly rows for each group. Your solution gives 3 rows for `id 2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not the most efficient solution, but it works:

```py
import numpy as np

df = df.sort_values('id')
# next 3 lines: for each group find the separation
df['range_idx'] = range(0, df.shape[0])
df['mean_rank_group'] = df.groupby(['id'])['range_idx'].transform(np.mean)
df['separate_column'] = df['range_idx'] < df['mean_rank_group']

# groupby itself with the help of additional column
df.groupby(['id', 'separate_column'], as_index=False)['name'].agg(','.join).drop(
    columns='separate_column')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit convoluted approach but it does the work;

```
def func(s: pd.Series):
    mid = max(s.shape[0]//2 ,1)
    l1 = ' '.join(list(s[:mid]))
    l2 = ' '.join(list(s[mid:]))
    return [l1, l2]

df_new = df.groupby('id').agg(func)

df_new["name1"]= df_new["name"].apply(lambda x: x[0])
df_new["name2"]= df_new["name"].apply(lambda x: x[1])


df = df_new.drop(labels="name", axis=1).stack().reset_index().drop(labels = ["level_1"], axis=1).rename(columns={0:"name"}).set_index("id")
```